# 100+ slides in slider, how to optimize loading speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have made a slider with 100+ slides, every slides have 5 images. So It loads more. sometimes page dead. So how to optimize page loading speed.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of things affect boosting website speed performance. you can check your speed from variouse testing tool

- http://pingdom.com
- https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

from there you can see the responce and request time interval for fetching files and its size. google allow you to download compressed file(compressed and concated js/css and optimized image).

also some htaccess configuration will help you too:

```
<FilesMatch "\.js\.gzip$">
    AddType "text/javascript" .gzip
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.css\.gzip$">
    AddType "text/css" .gzip
</FilesMatch>
```

AddEncoding gzip .gzip

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text / css "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType image / gif "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType image / jpeg "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType image / png "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType image / jpg "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType image / x-icon "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType application / font-woff "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType application / x-font-ttf "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType application / svg + xml "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType application / vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType application / x-shockwave-flash "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType application / javascript "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType application / x-javascript "access plus 7 days"
```

Let's disable  hotlinking for images with either forbidden or providing custom image option

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ – [NC,F,L]

Header set Connection keep-alive
```

Comment: Actually i have made simple optmization like this. but for first time page loads more so i am looking for java script when image on view port it loads.